# Drupal 8: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 module, called report. 
In my report.routing.yml file, I have:

```
report.dbtesting:
  path: '/dbtesting'
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\report\Controller\dbTest::showContent
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

In my report.services.yml, I have:

```
services:
      drupal.testcontroller:
        class: Drupal\report\Controller\dbtest
        arguments: ['@database']
```

In my dbtest.php controller, I have:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\report\controller;


use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;

class dbtest extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
   */
  private $connection;

  public function __construct(Connection $connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
  }

  public function showContent() {
    return [
      '#markup' => 'test'
    ];
  }
}
```

When I go to mysite.com/dbtest, I encountered the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   **ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function**
>   **Drupal\report\controller\dbtest::__construct(), 0 passed in**
>   /mysite.com/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/ControllerBase.php
>   on line 118 **and exactly 1 expected in**
>   Drupal\report\controller\dbtest->__construct() (line 16 of
>   /mysite.com/modules/custom/report/src/Controller/dbtest.php).

I have already added an argument for the db connection and did exactly as recommended in Symfony. There is no reliable example on the Drupal site. I also checked this forum, https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-07-22/solved-need-some-help-with-a-simple.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it from this:

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $form = new static(
      $container->get('database')
    );

    return $form;
  }
```

to:

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('database')
    );
  }
```